# State Transition Matrix of a time varying linear dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stochastic-matrices

> Given $$\dot x = A(t)x(t)$$ where $A(t)$ is a [Metzler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metzler_matrix) matrix whose column sums are zeros at all time $t$, prove that the state transition matrix of the system is a left (or right) stochastic matrix for all time $t$ and $t_0$.

---

Just need some hints on where to start.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand the "all time $t$ and $t_0$" part.

Comment: Let $X(t)$ be a fundamental system of $x'=A(t)x$, $X(t_0)=I$. Since $A(t)$ is quasipositive (a Metzler-matrix) all entries of $X(t)$ are nonnegative $(t \ge t_0)$. Let $p=(1,1,\dots,1)$. Now $pX'(t)=pA(t)X(t)=0$, that is $pX(t)=pX(t_0)=p$. So $X(t)$ is left stochastic $(t \ge t_0)$.