# State Transition Matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stochastic-matrices

A similar question to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440659/state-transition-matrix-of-a-time-varying-linear-dynamical-system), but now row sums are zeros. I don't think the suggeted approach in the comment works anymore.

> Given $$\dot x = A(t)x(t)$$ where $A(t)$ is a [Metzler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metzler_matrix) matrix whose row sums are zeros at all time $t$, prove that the state transition matrix of the system is a left (or right) stochastic matrix for all time $t$ and $t_0$.

---

Just need some hints on where to start.

Answer (score 0):

If $M(t)$ is the state transition matrix from time $0$ to time $t$,
then $$x(t)=M(t)x(0) \quad (*) \,.$$ Pick $x(0)={\bf 1}$ (the all ones vector) to find that for this initial condition, the solution of
$$\dot x = A(t)x(t)$$ is $x(t)={\bf 1}$ for all $t$, because $A{\bf 1}=0$ by assumption.Thus by $(*)$, we have
${\bf 1}=M(t){\bf 1}$, i.e., $M(t)$ is stochastic for all $t$.

Comment: thank you, but how do you show that M is a nonnegative matrix