# Non-negative fundamental Matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, fundamental-solution

> Given a system of n homogeneous linear ordinary differential equations $$\dot x = M(t)x(t)$$ where $M(t)$ is a [Metzler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metzler_matrix) matrix at any time $t$, prove that the fundamental matrix to this system of ODEs is non-negative(all entries are non-negative).

---

Edit: I know this holds if $A(t)$ is constant as the solution is a matrix exponential of the Metzler matrix, but I couldn't find reference the case when A(t) actually depends on t.

Comment: What you tried to do? This is obviously an exercise.

Comment: The same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440911/state-transition-matrix . Also the same question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440659/state-transition-matrix-of-a-time-varying-linear-dynamical-system .

Comment: @JohnB Then, it may be the question of an exam...

Comment: Just want to find the reference to: M being Metzler implies that the fundamental matrix is positive. One of the questions in the comment is actually asked by me.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\dot{\Phi}(t)=M(t)\Phi(t),\ \Phi(0)=I$, where $\Phi$ is the fundamental matrix function. Note that $\Phi(0)$ is nonnegative.

A Taylor expansion at $t=0$ gives $\Phi(\epsilon)=I+\epsilon M(t)+o(\epsilon)$, which shows that the matrix $\Phi(t)$ will be nonnegative on $[0,t_1]$ for some $t_1>0$.

Now let $t_2\ge t_1$ to be the first time for which (at least) one of the entries of $\Phi(t_2)$ is zero. Let $i,j$ be such that $\Phi_{ij}(t_2)=0$, then we have that

$$\dot{\Phi}_{ij}(t_2)=\sum_{k=1}^nm_{ik}(t_2)\Phi_{kj}(t_2)=m_{ii}(t_2)\Phi_{ij}(t_2)+\sum_{k\ne i}m_{ik}(t_2)\Phi_{kj}(t_2).$$

Since $\Phi_{ij}(t_2)=0$, then we have that
$$\dot{\Phi}_{ij}(t_2)=\sum_{k\ne i}m_{ik}(t_2)\Phi_{kj}(t_2)$$

which is nonnegative since $M(t)$ is Metzler and $\Phi_{kj}(t_2)\ge0$ for all $k\ne i$. Therefore, when $\Phi_{ij}(t)$ reaches zero, its derivative is necessarily nonnegative at that point, which means that the value never becomes negative.

Comment: thank you, but may I ask how can I found proof to this property: Φ(ϵ)=I+ϵM(t)+o(ϵ)? Also, I'm new to linear system theory/dynamical systems, do you have any recommended textbooks

Comment: The expansion is a Taylor expansion at zero. For the books, you may check the book by Ogota or the videos by Brian Douglass.